# Unicode surrogates character encoding c#

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding, decoding

I've got problem with Unicode characters. When I want to encode surrogates character (between `D800` and `DFFF`) it encodes as `FFFD`. I used `Encoding.Unicode.GetString()` method **it doesn't work** and `Decoder.GetChars()` method **it doesnt work with every surrogate character**.

I use following codes:

Encoding Codes:

```
string unicodeChars="a\uD800\uDA65";
FileStream stream=new FileStream (@"unicode_encoding.txt",FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write);
byte[] buffer=Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(unicodeChars);

stream.Write(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
stream.Close();
```

Decoding Codes:

```
string decodedUnicodeChars;
FileStream stream2=new FileStream (@"unicode_encoding.txt",FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
StreamReader reader=new StreamReader(stream2,Encoding.Unicode);

decodedUnicodeChars=reader.ReadToEnd();

foreach(char c in decodedUnicodeChars)
{
   Console.Write("{0} ",Convert.ToInt32(c).ToString("X4"));
}
```

Output is:

```
0061 FFFD FFFD
```

Comment: [Hans Passant](http://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) is right. Your value D800,DA65 is not valid, because DA65 is not within range. The second value needs to be between DC00 and DFFF.

Answer (score 4):

```
 string unicodeChars="a\uD800\uD565";
```

This is a case of gigo, Garbage In, Garbage Out.  The surrogate is not valid, the second one must be in the range \uDC00..\uDFFF.